# Interchange values of two rows in pandas for selected columns in order of row and column:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've been trying this for a while now, but I can't seem to get the results.
After searching a lot (including stackoverflow) I coudn't find any solutions:

Here's the data:

```
k   l   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
k_1 0   1   2   3   8   4
k_2 1   1   2   5   8   6
```

This is the desired result:

```
k   l   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
k_1 0   1   2   3   8   4
k_2 1   1   2   5   8   6
k_1 0   1   2   5   8   4
k_2 1   1   2   3   8   6
k_1 0   1   2   3   8   6
k_2 1   1   2   5   8   4
```

So far this is the closest I could get:

```
k   l   x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
k_1 0   1   2   3   8   4
k_2 1   1   2   5   8   6
k_1 0   1   2   5   8   6
k_2 1   1   2   3   8   4
k_1 0   1   2   3   8   4
k_2 1   1   2   5   8   6
```

This is what I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['k_1', 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 4], ['k_2', 1, 1, 2, 5, 8, 6]],
                  columns = ['k', 'l', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5'])

def get_ds(df):
    arr = np.where(df.iloc[0, :] != df.iloc[1, :])
    ind = [i for i in arr[0] if i not in [0, 1]]
    return ind

def intchng_df(df):
    temp_df = pd.concat([df] * (len(get_ds(df)) + 1), ignore_index=True)
    return temp_dfI

temp_df = intchng_df(df)

i = 2
for col, row in temp_df.iteritems():
    if col in [temp_df.columns[c] for c in get_ds(df)]:
        t = temp_df.loc[i, col]
        temp_df.loc[i, col] = temp_df.loc[i+1, col]
        temp_df.loc[i+1, col] = t

temp_df
```

Basically, What I'm trying to achieve:

- Find Columns which have different values except `k` & `l` -> `x3` & `x5` in this
  case using `get_ds()`
- Find all possible combination of row values for these two columns -> using `intchng_df()`.
- Leave the original two rows intact and interchange remaining row values for each column one by one.

As given in the desired result, for `x3` **row2** and **row3** were interchanged, and then for `x5` **row 4** and **row 5** were interchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
unique_entries = df.filter(like='x').apply(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False).all())

permutation_df = df.copy()
for col in unique_entries[~unique_entries].index:
    (df.loc['k1',col],df.loc['k2',col]) = (df.loc['k2',col],df.loc['k1',col])
    permutation_df = pd.concat([permutation_df,df])
    (df.loc['k1',col],df.loc['k2',col]) = (df.loc['k2',col],df.loc['k1',col])
```

note that in Python you can swap using tuples which makes it more compact.

Comment: Hi nice solution but is there any neater version of doing the same